# Multi capturing groups in scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to go from

```
val s: String = "sometextHere[a][b][c]"
```

to

```
val x = "sometextHere"
val y = List("a", "b", "c")
```

The number of "[...]" is 1+.
I've got something pretty hacky but I feel like there must be a better solution

```
val bracketMatcher = "\\[(\\w+)\\]".r
val listMatcher = s"^(\\w+)((?:$bracketMatcher)+)".r

listMatcher.findAllIn(chunk) match {
      case matchIterator if matchIterator.hasNext =>
        val matchData = matchIterator.matchData.next()
        val indexesMatch = bracketMatcher.findAllIn(matchData.group(2)).matchData.flatMap(_.subgroups).toList
        val a = matchData.group(1) // This is "sometextHere"
        val b = indexesMatch // This is List("a", "b", "c")
      case _ => ...
```

Comment: This has a potential to become really messy. What happens in cases where you have an uneven number of square braces and/or in the wrong order, and/or at different parts of the String. i.e. `val s: String = "some[[d]x[e]]][[textHere[a][b][c]"`

Comment: Good point, however in this case I'm only interested in cases which match exactly this pattern, anything more complex than this (nested brackets etc...) should not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexes are easier to write in triple quotes.  Also, you don't have to match the entire thing at once:

```scala
def allMatches(s: String): (String, List[String]) = {
  val bracketMatcher = """\[(\w+)\]""".r
  val startMatcher = """^(\w+)\[""".r

  val first = startMatcher.findFirstMatchIn(s).get.group(1)
  val matches = bracketMatcher.findAllMatchIn(s)
  val indexes = matches.map(_.group(1)).toList
  (first, indexes)
}

allMatches("sometextHere[a][b][c]")
```

Robert gave a good warning, though.  Make sure your input data has no nesting, or you won't be able to handle it with regular expressions.  If you have nesting, you'll have to use a proper parser.

Comment: That does look a little bit better, I'll take it thanks !